# Using classes in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

Excuse me if i sound like a complete noob or use improper terminology below.

I am trying to create a class in vb.net from which multiple form class can inherit from. So in the 'form class' if i say, get a list from the user, sent it to the 'seperate class' to order the list and then pass the list back to the form class to save in a database or do whatever with how would i proceed.

So far this is what i have done.

below is the class itself without the contents

```
Public Class RandomClassName

End Class
```

Below is what i have done to 'inherit' from the above class

```
Public Class frmStudentLogin
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Dim ValidUserNameLength As Boolean
Inherits RandomClassName
```

I would like to know how i would set up the code to allow me to properly inherit from and refer to the class link.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont quite follow but if `frmStudentLogin` is a Form, it cant inherit from any class because it already inherits from `Windows.System.Forms.Form` .  Multilple inheritance is not supported.  Your form(s) could create and use `RandomClassName` objects though.  Your entire app could share one copy as well.  Based on the user name var, you might be looking for a User class to store user data, validate it etc?  (You ought not try to share DBConnections that way anyway - they should be used and disposed of each time)

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at [Data binding concepts in .NET windows forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3665/Data-binding-concepts-in-NET-windows-forms) or google for [vb winforms data binding](https://www.google.ch/search?q=vb+winforms+data+binding).

Comment: However, while difficult to justify knowing what he wants to share, he could make the RandomClassName inherit from Form and (after fixing the syntax error) he could inherit the frmStudentLogin from RandomClassName

Comment: Ok. Is there any way I could then say refer to the one function on a certain from say formStudentLogin from another form

Comment: Its best not to design your app around forms.  Forms are for collecting user input.  You can create classes that you can use from any form though.  After looking at a good deal of your code (all?) the last week or so, I would put off Classes until you grasp the concept of Scope.  I'm not being unkind, I just know what you will run into

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which problem are you trying to solve with this inheritance approach, but surely you could inherit a form class (MyForm) from another class (BaseForm) provided that the other class (BaseForm) inherits from the form base class (Form).

At that point you could insert in the MyForm all the function that you want to share between your forms but be aware that, in this scenario, every form will be affected by your BaseForm class

I will show an example tested in LinqPAD

```
Sub Main

    Dim x = New MyForm()
    x.Show()

End Sub

Public Class MyForm
    Inherits BaseForm

    Public Sub New ()
        Dim txt = New TextBox()
        txt.Multiline = True
        txt.Height = 200

        'Here you could use the GetAList from the BaseForm class
        ' and use it to set the initial text for the multiline textbox.
        txt.AppendText (String.Join(Environment.NewLine, GetAList().ToArray()))
        Me.Controls.Add(txt)
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class BaseForm
    Inherits Form

    ' Common methods required by your uplevel forms
    Public Function GetAList() As List(Of String)
        Dim a = New List(Of String)() From
            {"ABC", "DEF", "GHJ"}
        Return a
    End Function

End Class
```